# Cannot get my base64 string to decode on my javascript client

Tags: java, javascript, utf-8, websocket, base64

I am sending data from my java tomcat server to my browser using a WebSocket. I get the error: "Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: 'atob' failed: The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded."

Here is my code:

(java server code):

```
public void open(Session session)
{
  String base64ImageString = generateImageString();
  try
  {
     session.getBasicRemote().sendText(base64ImageString);
  }
  catch(IOException e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

private String generateImageString()
{
  int imageData[] = new int[2];
  imageData[0] = 255;
  imageData[1] = 128;
  String base64Image = "";
  for(int i = 0; i < imageData.length; i++)
  {
    try
    {
      base64Image += Base64.encode(Integer.toString(imageData[i]).getBytes("UTF8"));
      catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    } 
    catch( UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  return base64Image;
}
```

(JavaScript code):

```
function onMessage(evt)
{
  base64ImageDataString = evt.data;
  imageDataString = window.atob(base64ImageDataString);
}
```

My base64 string looks like this on the java and javascript side: `[B@74193bd0[B@24a6103c`

I am using org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.Base64 if it matters. I am really stumped :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My base64 string looks like this on the java and javascript side: `[B@74193bd0[B@24a6103c`

That's not base64. That's the concatenation of the result of calling `toString()` on two byte arrays. You're using a method which returns a `byte[]`, not a string, which means your string concatenation is inappropriate. You could use `Base64.encodeAsString` - or use a different base64 library entirely (e.g. [the iharder one](http://iharder.net/base64)). But really you shouldn't be doing any string concatenation.

Your `generateImageString` code *is* completely broken. It's not at all clear why you'd convert an integer to a string, get the UTF-8 representation of that, and then convert the byte array to base64... and then do that in a loop. That's just not the way to get anything meaningful.

I suspect you should *actually* be starting with a `byte[]` rather than an `int[]` - it's not clear what those values are meant to be - but then you want a *single* call to `Base64.encode`, passing the `byte[]` in. If you're calling `Integer.toString` or concatenating bits of Base64 data, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Is it possible to go from int[] to byte[] to a base64 string and then reverse that on the javascript side? I did not realize how far off I was...

Comment: @smuggledPancakes: Yes, that's entirely possible - but you need to work out how you want to map the `int[]` to a `byte[]`, e.g. in terms of endianness.

Answer (score -1):

[B@24a6103c represents a byte array as a string since Base64.encode returns a byte array.

You need to convert the byte array to a string before concatenating it to the String base64Image

I think you want to do this:

```
base64Image += new String(Base64.encode(Integer.toString(imageData[i]).getBytes("UTF8")));
```

Comment: No, that's absolutely *not* what the OP should do.